# Find text in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a web browser control, already navigated to a page. Now I want to search for a specific text in the page, and scroll to the first occurrence.

Being able to scroll to other occurrences is a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

webBrowser1.Select();
SendKeys.Send("^f");

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works in a `WebBroswer`. We make the broswer(IE/FF/etc) window scroll to some text with the following code:

```
//source code of http://www.sample.com/sample.html
<html>
...
<span name="aim">KeyWord</span>
...
</html>
```

If I want the window to scroll to the "KeyWord", simply visit `http://www.sample.com/sample.html#aim`

Using `string document = myWebBrowser.DocumentText` to get the source code of the page, and search the text in the string, get its node name, and navigate it using `#`.

Comment: Actually the problem is not scrolling to a specific node; that has been done. Finding a selection of text that matches the search query is the main problem.

Comment: I bit of detail must be added here... Searching in the text results in a index in the string. Finding the node that contained that string is not that trivial: The matched text might be the result of multiple text nodes merged into a node.

Answer (score 0):

See this if it helps:

```
string PageSource = null;
PageSource = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml();
if (Strings.InStr(PageSource, stringtoFind) > 0) {
  ...insert an Anchor tag here and then use 
   WebBrowser1.Navigate to go to the the new URL with the #Anchor tag
} else {
...whatever else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way...

Use the `Ctrl` + `F` Key to invoke `Find`, native to the WebBrowser Control?